# Unexpected password autofill with Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I have integrated Firebase Dynamics Links into my app (using `<myapp>.page.link` domain) and it's all working fine. However, I have now found that in my login and registration screens I get username/password autofill appearing for website `page.link`. I'm not currently using autofill, and don't have the `webcredentials` entitlement, so this is very strange. Has anyone else come across this and know how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing it every time for each new project with dynamic links.

I think that firebase's `apple-app-site-association` posted at `<yourapp>.page.link` is the only credible source of info it can find (even though it doesn't have `webcredentials`). Basically it looks like after failing to find `webcredentials` anywhere it falls back to the only available file with `applinks`.

The easiest way to prevent this is to take initiative from firebase and post own `apple-app-site-association` file with `webcredentials` at your site (with proper "webcredentials:<your.domain>" counterpart added into the Associated Domains capability).

Comment: Adding `webcrentials` to `apple-app-site-association` on my own site seemed to avoid the issue.