# Does the associated domain file from Firebase Dynamic Links work for password autofill?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to implement password autofill and strong password suggestions in an iOS app. I know that in order for this to work it is required that I have an associated domain setup. I am currently using Firebase Dynamic Links for deep linking, which automatically sets up an `apple-app-site-association` file, and I figured I could use this for password autofill. For some reason it currently isn't working and I'm not sure why.

My textfields look like this:

```
VStack() {
    TextField("Username", text: $viewModel.email)
        .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
        .textContentType(.username)        
    TextField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
        .textContentType(.newPassword)
}
```

However, when I launch them the debugger shows this error:

`"Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: com.***.*** due to error: Cannot save passwords for this app. Make sure you have set up Associated Domains for your app and AutoFill Passwords is enabled in Settings"`

I have `Autofill Passwords` enabled in the settings, and my dynamic links are successfully launching the app and being parsed, which tells me that the associated domain is setup correctly. The only thing I can think of is that maybe the format of the apple-app-site-association file that is setup by Firebase doesn't work with autofill. The file looks like this:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "team_id.com.***.***",
            "paths": ["NOT /_/*", "/*"]
        }]
    }
}
```

I know there are a lot of similar posts to this already on SO, but I haven't found a solution that works yet. There's even [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233177/unexpected-password-autofill-with-firebase-dynamic-links) stating that implementing Firebase Dynamic Links triggered autofill unexpectedly, however I'm not sure if they're using something like Firebase Hosting which maybe could have triggered it.

Is anyone else successfully using the app-site-association file setup by Firebase Dynamic Links to implement password autofill?